# A word that means 'someone who always immediately cleans up after eating, keeps their room tidy..."

Tags: single-word-requests

... when they see people in need, they help. People who feel the need to do certain things like these.

Edit: I'm not looking for a word describing someone compulsively neat, but someone who has a certain consciousness of these things.

Comment: Someone "who always cleans up after eating [and who] keeps their room tidy" seems describable in completely different terms from someone who "when they see people in need, they help." Is there some reason why you find using one word for the first characteristic and another for the second unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Conscientious**

> (of a person) wishing to do what is right, especially to do one's work or duty well and thoroughly.
>    "a conscientious and hardworking clerk"
>
> synonyms:    diligent, industrious, punctilious, painstaking, sedulous, assiduous, dedicated, careful, meticulous, thorough, attentive, hard-working, studious, rigorous, particular;

Defined by Google

A conscientious person is one who is very aware of their surroundings and duties.  They're the opposite of careless.  [By some theories](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/unique-everybody-else/201507/resolving-the-conscientiousness-paradox), conscientiousness is one of the basic personality traits that define a person:

> Conscientiousness is a broad dimension of personality that encompasses a person’s predisposition to control their behavior in socially acceptable ways (Roberts, Jackson, Fayard, Edmonds, & Meints, 2009). Hence, people high on conscientiousness tend to be self-disciplined, think before they act, are goal-directed and follow socially prescribed rules and norms.

Answer (score 4):

Title does not match question content. Perhaps you could bring the two into better accord?
However:
**Neatnik**?

[Merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neatnik):

> a person who is compulsively neat

As might be expected: First use 1959

Answer (score 3):

From the more-general idea you give of "helps when help is needed", I would say ***considerate:***

> showing kindly awareness or regard for another's feelings, circumstances, etc.  ([m-w.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/considerate?s=t))

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thoughtful) offers some additional insight at its entry for ***thoughtful:***

> *thoughtful, considerate, attentive, solicitous*:
>   These adjectives mean having or showing concern for the well-being of others. Although *thoughtful* and *considerate* are often used interchangeably, *thoughtful* implies a tendency to anticipate needs or wishes, whereas *considerate* stresses sensitivity to another's feelings: *a thoughtful friend who brought me soup when I was sick; considerate, quiet neighbors*. *Attentive* suggests devoted, assiduous attention: *an excellent host who was attentive to the needs of his guests. Solicitous* implies deep concern, sometimes accompanied by worry: *a mother who is very solicitous of her asthmatic child.*

Answer (score 3):

[Fastidious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fastidious)

1. very careful about how you do something
2. liking few things : hard to please

**3. wanting to always be clean, neat, etc.**

Comment: This is also very close to what I want. Unfortunately, I cannot accept two answers...